# How to use gradle's apply plugin in Bazel BUILD?

Tags: java, android, firebase, bazel

In android gradle file when using Firebase we have to add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`.But I want to know that how to use this in Bazel? Without this my Firebase services are not starting.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a Gradle plugin with Bazel.

If you want to configure an Android app that uses Firebase in Bazel, you'll need to find some other way to perform the same work as the plugin.  Basically all the plugin does to configure Firebase is add some string resources to your app.  It should be easy to arrange that yourself.

The documentation for the added string resources is [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin).